# How to make it so that the color you pick in a JColorChooser changes the color of the font in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jcolorchooser

I'm making a basic Text Editor and i want it so where you can select a color in the JColorChooser and the color that you chose will be the new color of the Text in the JTextArea. This is the code for the JColorChooser

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JColorChooser color = new JColorChooser();

        panel.add(color);

        int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Pick a Color", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, -1);
        if(x == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
            <Code Here>
        }
        if(x == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){

        }else{

        }
```

and the JText Area's code is

```
static JTextArea textArea;

private Font textFont;
```

NVM IT HAS BEEN ANSWERED

```
Color newColor = color.getColor();
                textArea.setForeground(newColor);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html).

The `ColorChooserDemo` will show you how to do this. It change the foreground of a JLabel, but the concept would be the same for a JTextArea.

Also, the tutorial example will show you how to better structure your code. You should NOT be using static variables in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Just a question though would you know how to make it that the JColorChooser on changes the color of the text that you highlighted?

Comment: That is not supported in a JTextArea. You will need to use a JTextPane for that. Again. read the tutorial. The section on `Text Component Features` has example of using styled text in a JTextPane.

Comment: Thanks just one more question though, is there an AWT version of the JColorChooser, because in my opinion the java one doesn't look the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color newColor = color.getColor();
textArea.setForeground(newColor);
```